# Bootstrap 4 docs examples don't work on CodePen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codepen

For example [this code does not work](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offset-classes) as can be demonstrated by [this pen](https://codepen.io/nikoliazekter/pen/RjaYwV). Switching to Bootstrap 3 and changing `offset-{breakpoint}-*` to `col-{breakpoint}-offset-*` seems to work though. Why is that?

Comment: I check the CSS from `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css` there is no offset class for grid in beta-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bootstrap 4.0 beta2 - because they brought back offsetting columns only in this release:
https://codepen.io/svitch/pen/xPVaZw

```css
.row > div {
  background-color: #ccc;
  outline: 2px solid #777;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}

.row > .col, .row > [class^=col-] {
    padding-top: .75rem;
    padding-bottom: .75rem;
    background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">.col-md-4 .offset-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">.col-md-6 .offset-md-3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Now... why doesn't https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment work on CodePen?

Comment: Docs should probably mention how to actually make it work. Very confusing for a beginner. Anyways thanks a lot!